# deactivating or disabling other game objects during capturing a frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

while rendering and capturing a frame during the game, how can I deselect or deactivate some game objects those I don't want to be in the captured frame?

Can anyone please tell me how can it be achieved?

Comment: Deactivate the objects, take screenshot, activate the object. You want someone to show you how to activate/deactivate? A simple googling should fix that for you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should use SetActive code